# how to add ion scroll directive in div?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I  am trying to implement this example in ionic framework
here is the code which i am trying to implement
http://plnkr.co/edit/LjAoAPFDx0eVPkx3dKfu?p=preview .In which only six element is present in dom in any situation .I am trying to implement same in ionic framework using  but it is not added ion scroll in my div why ?

how to add ion scroll in that ?? so that smooth scrolling occur .

here is my plunker of my demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/WJcbpkqJvzmMWXrg8WpH?p=preview

can we add ion scroll in that ?

```
  <ion-scroll>
  <div vs-repeat class="repeater-container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="item">
      {{item.text}}
    </div>
  </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: it seems that there is nothing wrong with your code. what do you mean by ion-scroll is not added??? is the {{item.text}} being rendered in the screen??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a certain amount of items at a time in a list you can use a collection repeat and then simply set item height to the height of the container div and then divide by six. Something similar to this. I used the height of the window but some idea. 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane ng-controller="main">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
       <div class="list">
         <div class="item" collection-repeat="item in thisArray" item-height="height"></div>
       </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);

angular.module('app').controller('main', function($scope){
  $scope.thisArray = [];

  for(x=0; x<100; x++){
  $scope.thisArray.push(x);
  }

  $scope.height = screen.height/9;

})
```

Comment: as you change the item-height it will change how many items show  up in the view at any time

Comment: the number is arbitrary. If you want to show 9 items you divide by 9, 6 for 6.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is nothing wrong with your code. what do you mean by ion-scroll is not added??? is the {{item.text}} being rendered in the screen? Perhaps it is blank?

if the partial views is not rendered, you need to firstly declare ion-view as the parent element in each partials views,

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**partialview1.html**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-scroll>
    <div>
      //more content
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
```